# IntelliJ commit warning levels

Tags: version-control, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA, when I commit to subversion, I am presented with a dialog box asking me if I would like to commit, and that I have X number of warnings.

Is there a way to set the level for which warnings are included in this message? Currently it is including all warnings, including "typo" level warnings. I don't want to disable inspection on typos, but I don't want them to show up as warnings on commit either. Is this possible?

I am on version 12.1.4.

Comment: perhaps this will be of help http://stackoverflow.com/a/16369750/750216

Answer (score 3):

There is not. You can only turn the code analysis on or off. That would be a useful feature I think. I recommend you make a feature request for it: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com

A work around would be to define an alternate code inspection profile. Then change inspection profiles before the commit, and then change it back after. The quickest access to changing the inspection profile is to click the Hector the Inspector icon [image] in the bottom right corner of the status bar, then click configure inspections.